# Convert string into keycode in android

Tags: java, android, keyevent

Assume, I have a `String s = "Hello World"`. How can I get the equivalent keycode for each character? I know the way to convert it by using,

`char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();`

while triggering the event. In my case I dont have the **KeyEvent**.

Assume, in my case, I didn't use **AndroidSDK** and I tried it in java. I need to find out the equivalent value of each character.

I have an option for doing the above scenario by storing all **keycode** and **character** values in **Map** then compare my string by reading as a character.

Can you advise whether my option is good? If not, can any one give the best suggestion regard my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **KeyStroke**, have a look at this example:

```
KeyStroke kStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a');
System.out.println(ks.getKeyCode());
```

Also have a look here: [KeyStroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(int,%20int))

You can use the above example to get all the key codes from a string. 
Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for suggestion.. but in your case it just display ASCII value of character

Comment: @No_Rulz Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html